# How we can view all the Office 365 groups' sites that have been created inside our sharepoint online tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-groups

I have received a request from our customer that they need a way to view all the Office 365 groups' sites that have been created by the users. now i login to the sharepoint online central admin, but inside the  `/_layouts/15/online/SiteCollections.aspx` page, i can ONLY see the regular site collections that have been created. but not sure how we can view all the Office 365 groups' sites that have been created by the users ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of the Site Collection page in the admin center there may be a link for "Try the preview".

This will also list the Groups sites. (You may not have access to it yet.)

```
https://yourDomain-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/siteManagement
```

Otherwise, you can use the SharePoint Online PowerShell cmdlets.

```
Connect-SPOService https://yourDomain-admin.sharepoint.com
Get-SPOSite -Template GROUP#0 | select url
```

You can download them here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35588

Pictures for comment below...

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, so only admin users can view the Office 365 groups available ? or we can expose this info for end users as well?

Comment: Your users can click "Discover" in OWA to see a list of public groups. From there they can click "All Groups" or search for a public group.

Comment: can you please explain from where exactly the user need to click on the "Discover" ??

Comment: On the left nav of the Outlook/OWA page click "more" under the groups section.  Then click "Discover" at the top. Then click "All groups at the top right. (I added two pictures to the answer above.)